# SOAPUI: How to make properties that have been downloaded from an external file in "Properties" step, common to the entire suite

Tags: soapui

Hy all,

I should parameterize my test cases that everyone can run them on your PC.For this purpose, I
download properties from the system property.file (${#Env#INVDIR}/.../cfg/${#Env#USERNAME}.properties) by means of "Properties" step and than I want use this properties as parameters in all test suite.

But now I should create "Properties" step at the beginning of each test case.
How can I make properties that have been downloaded once general for all test suite?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Copy them to TestSuite level via PropertyTransfer Step: http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/transfering-property-values.html